# Utilize push notifications in Jquery Mobile/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, jquery-mobile

So I am trying to find a way to use push notifications in a Jquery Mobile app.  Has anyone ever had any success doing this?  Any insight would be very helpful.

Are there any JavaScript libraries that would enable this functionality if not immediately included in JQM?  I have started investigating [Pusher](http://pusher.com/docs), but am not sure about its viability yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can try out plugins for phonegap to try out push nitifications,
there is pusher as u mentioned. also Urbanairship.
also check out some info in this question - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927696/plugins-for-phonegap-apps-for-push-notifications-for-android-iphone-and-blackbe

Comment: Thanks for this.  I am going to check Urbanairship out.